# How agent maintain a specific distance in queue line?

Tags: simulation, anylogic

I am using a queue and a delay. Now when agents are in the queue, they don't maintain specific distances and collide into each other. shown in the image below.

> **Note:** For queue i am using line and for delay in am using node.

[image]

**Questions**

1. How I can achieve safe distance between agents when they are in the queue.
2. Same problem is happening when 2 agents enter in the simulation at same time. How I can maintain the distance between them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Agents do not care about distance at all. Animating agents in a queue is just that: animation.

However, you can indirectly pretend they keep some distance by making the animation line longer or shorter.

And if you want proper distancing, do not use agents but other agent types (peds, cars, material items...)

Comment: Using car type agent solve this issue. Thank you for your help.